# Workflow for developing Laravel Packages

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

I'm developing my first Laravel Package, and I realize that my workflow contains much more steps for publishing each modification.

Here is my workflow:

1. I create a Fresh Laravel 5.4 install. Inside, I create a package/author/name/src where I code my plugin.
2. I run my tests
3. Once I have made my change and want to publish it:
   a.I push it to my Git rep
   b.I tag it with version number
   c.In my main project, I run composer update
4. I check that nothing broke with the integration

This is quite a lot of changes for each little change I want to see in my main project....

Is there a way not to publish any single change, just doing local?

Comment: following, i would love to see a good workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can locally develop a package and use it without publishing it. The workflow is: create a packages directory outside of your `Laravel` project then create the package directory in it, for example the directory structure should look something like this:

```
- my-laravel-project
- packages
- - my-package-1
- - - composer.json
- - my-package-2
- - - composer.json
```

Then, in your `Laravel` project's `composer.json` file, add the `repositories` section like given below and add an entry into the `require` section for each local package, for example:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../packages/my-package-1"
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../packages/my-package-2"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "my/package-1": "*",
        "my/package-2": "*"
    }
}
```

In this example, I've two different packages inside `packages` directory and I've added both packages in the `Laravel` project. The `repositories` section describes the package type and path/url for each package so composer can find them locally and `require` section is simply requiring the dependencies as usual. You may check more on [Composer's website](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path).

Comment: but then shouldn't I need 2 composer.json? 1 for dev, and 1 for master?

Comment: The `composer.json` will be always one per package.

Comment: but for my prod app, should I want "url": "https://url-to-git.git"
        }, instead of path to local package? This would ok for dev, but not for prod, am I wrong?

Comment: Once you done with your local development then publish it and rest of the procedures are same. You can remove the local repository dependencies and switch to git repo in your `composer.json`.

Comment: I implemented it, but it is not getting latest local changes :( it is getting the last versionned commit, (0.8.6)??? Also, if I try with vcs, it do the same, looking for version, is it normal???